# Drools working concurrency drools 5.5.0

Tags: drools, drools-flow

How to use drools in an environment where multiple users are working or accessing rules for the same operation.
Considering a drl which contains 5 rules and now these rules are being accessed by multiple users. This is obvious that rules will be stored in knowledgesession. Each time when a request happens system will do i/o and loads dt and drls then a new knowledgesession will be created.
We are going to have more than 1500 rules which will be managed in 150+ dts and 150+ drls.

A sample code lead will be appreciated.

Comment: Multiple users or not: the question whether to use statefull or stateless session shouldn't be influenced by that. "Working at the same time" is rather vague.

Comment: Hi we are building an enterprise application which will be used by thousands of users. We are considering drools as rule engine for business logic but what would be rule access behavior when multiple users are accessing the same drl for same operation. I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: A DRL file is not what Drools executes. What Drools executes is a KieSession. So the question is: do you want the same KieSession to be concurrently accessed? Or do you want to reuse the same DRL in multiple KieSessions that will be individually accessed?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti can you please tell us pros and cons of both ways.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti i think we are going to have multiple kiesessions that will individually access DRLs.

Comment: I'm interested in this question because we have almost the same use case. Eack session will be independent and they'll access the same rules.

Comment: @SamuelMéndez we used dyna cache to store rules on server. I/O operations are now needed only once and then rules are available for access on basis of a key of HashMap.  This significantly increased the performance, Also used stateless session for better performance.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh Thanks! I'll read about it.

Comment: @SamuelMéndez Can you please elaborate on your approach how you implemented multi user support for rule edits

Comment: @user2355711 We took a different approach, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The same knowledge session can be used by multiple requests as the the rules remain constant independent of the requests.I have created a KIE session when application loads which is independent of requests made.